# Unable to connect other server in netsuite using Suitelet Script 2.0

Tags: netsuite

I am new Netsuite script.I created Suitelet  script and tried to connect other SFTP server from Netsuite. I am not able connect other server.Please let me know how to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post the script that you already have.  That will help people assist you by validating your code.

Comment: 1. I Generated PasswordGUID for 3rd party Server using Suitelet script.                    2.PasswordGuid's value pass to schedule script (In script mention hostkey,Directory,username)

Comment: /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/log', 'N/https', 'N/redirect', 'N/task', 'N/record','N/runtime','N/sftp','N/file'],
function (serverWidget, log, redirect, task, record,runtime,sftp,file) {
function onRequest(context) {
var method = context.request.method;
var response = context.response;var request = context.request;

Comment: if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
var form = serverWidget.createForm({
title: 'Enter SFTP Credentials' });
form.addField({id: 'username',type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,label: 'Username'}).isMandatory = true;
var credField = form.addCredentialField({id: 'custfield_sftp_password_token',label: 'SFTP Password',restrictToScriptIds:['customscript_custsuitelet_script_sftp'], ///it is suitelet scriptid
restrictToDomains: ['serverName.domain.com'],restrictToCurrentUser: true 
}).isMandatory = true;credField.maxLength = 64;form.addSubmitButton();}
var request = context.request;

Comment: if (context.request.method === 'POST') {var passwordToken = request.parameters.custfield_sftp_password_token;
var form = serverWidget.createForm({title: 'PasswordGUID Response'});
form.addField({id: 'passwordguidresponse',type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,label: 'PasswordGUID Response',displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
}).defaultValue = passwordToken;      
form.addSubmitButton({label : 'Execute Scheduled Script'});}
response.writePage(form)}
return{onRequest: onRequest}});

Comment: /**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(["N/sftp","N/file"],
function(sftp,file) {function createFileActiveUser(){
      var preConnectionObj = {};
preConnectionObj.passwordGuid = '**********************';

Comment: preConnectionObj.url = '******************';
preConnectionObj.hostKey = 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA3DWUmOtLSpDew5Qryvx7OgCvGk2IjlbniOcozkYGG6ZbbFeQRyAbFOxMudPnr8FUM6Qr9AxiHC5KkF9STgw6ivmJK/aEKkRJQm3rCN6VRi7l8i5CtoU/d2UnuZv2WrjNv36xpbQ7O7PtAtB8Dbly0sC7n6Wpp8ia1dHR7RVpG01oHSLkBDAoDo9wpDBDKFYoX3UxvqRoYVXNTqqYWzwwPcpLZq7Kvx/XzXCzDZuQxfXURgbYibAfD1IG45lmCmASEScK++H5bSLMr4l3tYRkBVCL8MKLoDSCgJd2bhXozzknwryOtDJ3ijoic5r3lbHCR/Nde6UrGFzVRsOfS5LlDw==';

Comment: preConnectionObj.username = 'sarajkum';preConnectionObj.hostKeyType = 'RSA',preConnectionObj.port =22;preConnectionObj.directory = ****************;
// preConnectionObj.timeout = '20'
var sftpConnection = sftp.createConnection(preConnectionObj);
var fileObj = file.load({id: 68580});
/*sftpConnection.upload({directory: '/',file: fileObj,replaceExisting: true});*/
lreturn{execute: createFileActiveUser}});

Comment: Let me know how to submit suitelet script from call schedure script.

Comment: Could you put the code in your question? Anyway, when I had the problem with the SFTP connection, I simply dropped it. And I create a small server for  (s)FTP connections. I create few Suitelets that manage the GET and POST files in Netsuite. There is some serveless solutions too, from AWS and GOOGLE. The NS SFTP API are not ready for production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below script.
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/render', 'N/runtime', 'N/file', 'N/task','N/sftp'],
  function (ui, search, render, runtime, file, task,sftp) {
    /**
     * main function for suitelet
     * @param {object} ctx
     */

```
function onRequest(ctx) {

  var req = ctx.request;
  var res = ctx.response;
  var param = req.parameters;
  /**
   * create form is creating the UI for report generation
   */
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    // createForm(req, res, param);
    createForm(req, res, param);
  } else {
    generateReport(req, res, param);
  }
}

// R E Q U E S T
function createForm(req, res, param) {

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    var form = ui.createForm({
      title: 'Enter SFTP Credentials'
    });

    var username = form.addField({
                id: 'username',
                type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: 'Username'
            });
    username.isMandatory = true;

    var pwd = form.addCredentialField({
                id: 'custfield_sftp_password_token',
                label: 'SFTP Password',
                restrictToScriptIds: ['customscript_custsuitelet_script_sftp'],
                restrictToDomains: ['irpt-rtp-stg-01.cisco.com'],
                restrictToCurrentUser: true //Depends on use case
            });
    pwd.isMandatory = true;
    pwd.maxLength = 64;
    form.addSubmitButton({
      label: 'Generate Report'
    });

    res.writePage(form);
  }
}

// R E S P O N C E
function generateReport(req, res, param) {
  var param = req.parameters.custfield_sftp_password_token;
  log.debug('parameters', param);
  var myPwdGuid = param;
  var myHostKey = "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA3DWUmOtLSpDew5Qryvx7OgCvGk2IjlbniOcozkYGG6ZbbFeQRyAbFOxMudPnr8FUM6Qr9AxiHC5KkF9STgw6ivmJK/aEKkRJQm3rCN6VRi7l8i5CtoU/d2UnuZv2WrjNv36xpbQ7O7PtAtB8Dbly0sC7n6Wpp8ia1dHR7RVpG01oHSLkBDAoDo9wpDBDKFYoX3UxvqRoYVXNTqqYWzwwPcpLZq7Kvx/XzXCzDZuQxfXURgbYibAfD1IG45lmCmASEScK++H5bSLMr4l3tYRkBVCL8MKLoDSCgJd2bhXozzknwryOtDJ3ijoic5r3lbHCR/Nde6UrGFzVRsOfS5LlDw==";

  var connection = sftp.createConnection({
  username:username,
  passwordGuid: myPwdGuid,
  url: 'sftp://hostname/users/username',
  directory: '/',
  hostKey: myHostKey
  });
  log.debug('parameters', connection);



  //var passwordToken = req.parameters.customscriptrun_schedule_script_after;

  /*var script = runtime.getCurrentScript();

  var filters = {
        custscript_sftp_password_token: param
  };

  log.debug('filters', filters);

  var scriptTask = task.create({ taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT });
  // scriptTask.scriptId = 3920;
  scriptTask.scriptId = 'customscriptrun_schedule_script_after';
  scriptTask.deploymentId = 'customdeployrun_schedule_scrpt_after';
  scriptTask.params ={
    custscript_sftp_password_token: JSON.stringify(filters)
  };
  log.debug('workingtillhere');
  var scriptTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
  res.write("Your script is scheduled.")*/

}

return {
  onRequest: onRequest
};
```

});